# Using ProcessBuilder to start a service into my Android app but it only starts with "su" (root)

Tags: java, android, process, android-service, processbuilder

I am using `ProcessBuilder`, into my Android app, to start a service but it starts only if I put `su` before the actual command.

This works just fine:

```
su -c am startservice -a com.companyname.app.HELLO --ef opt 6 --ef ert -9
```

This one doesn't work:

```
am startservice -a com.companyname.app.HELLO --ef opt 6 --ef ert -9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. `am startservice` will not work without elevated privileges.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not doing anything wrong. `am startservice` will not work without root privileges.

Thanks to @CommonsWare for his answer.